proj4js converts EPSG 3946 into EPSG 4326, but the points are not located well
I have a .json file of points to put on a Leaflet map, and I have used the proj4js to convert them from the EPSG 3946 projection into the WGS84 EPSG 4326 one. All worked, but the points are not located where they should be: they are about 8 degrees latitude more towards south and a little bit more towards east. The same points look fine on QGIS, they place where they should be.
This is the .js script:
var pTransfo;

$.getJSON('transfo.json',function(data){
    
    proj4.defs("EPSG:3946", "+proj=lcc +lat_1=43 +lat_2=49 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=6 +x_0=1700000 +y_0=6200000 +datum=RGF93 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0");

    var fromProj = proj4('EPSG:3946');
    var toProj = proj4('EPSG:4326');
    
    function convertCoordinates(coordinates) {
    
    var convertedCoords = proj4(fromProj, toProj, [coordinates[0], coordinates[1]]);
    console.log('Coordonnées originales :', coordinates);
    console.log('Coordonnées converties :', convertedCoords);
    return [convertedCoords[0], convertedCoords[1]];
}

    data.features.forEach(function(feature) {
        if (feature.geometry.type === "Point") {
            feature.geometry.coordinates = convertCoordinates(feature.geometry.coordinates);
        }
});

And I have already added this line in the html: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.6.0/proj4-src.js"></script> after the jquery and leaflet line.
Why this delay of location?

https://epsg.io/3946.proj4js has the definition proj4.defs("EPSG:3946","+proj=lcc +lat_0=46 +lon_0=3 +lat_1=45.25 +lat_2=46.75 +x_0=1700000 +y_0=5200000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs"); does that fix your issue?

No, no change... In the end, I made the conversion directly into the data base, created another 2 columns, x and y, and fill them through QGIS.

The issue is most likely the order of your EPSG:3946 coordinates. Since I don't have your data to test, I can only guess though. However, I wrote an example using 1124390.4605155424, 5490541.680680278 (x, y) for Le Conquet near Brest in Bretagne.
The conversation output is -4.773869999999995, 48.36004666665183 (lng, lat). If I pass the EPSG:3946 coordinate in its reversed order (y, x), then I also get a coordinate that is way off.
In addition, I am using the projection definition suggested by Jaromanda X in his comment.
// x, y
const leConquetEPSG3946 = [1124390.4605155424, 5490541.680680278];

proj4.defs('EPSG:3946', '+proj=lcc +lat_0=46 +lon_0=3 +lat_1=45.25 +lat_2=46.75 +x_0=1700000 +y_0=5200000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs');

const proj3946 = proj4('EPSG:3946');
const proj4326 = proj4('EPSG:4326');

const result = proj4(proj3946, proj4326, leConquetEPSG3946);

// -4.773869999999995, 48.36004666665183
console.log(result);

Here is a working example (with loading the projection definition for EPSG:3946 from spatialreference.org on the fly):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>StackOverflow Question 79049517</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" />

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.12.1/proj4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    #map {
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .reference-marker .circle {
      background-color: #f07819;
      border-radius: 50%;
      height: 20px; width: 20px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>

    // x, y
    const leConquetEPSG3946 = [1124390.4605155424, 5490541.680680278];

    // lat, lng
    const leConquetEPSG4326 = [48.36004669356216, -4.773869943507622];

    const map = L.map('map')
          .setView(leConquetEPSG4326, 16);

    map.attributionControl
      .setPrefix('<a href="https://leafletjs.com/">Leaflet</a>');

    L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 19,
      // add link to attribution, omitted in this code example
      // due to width limit, i.e., avoid horizontal scrolling
      attribution: '&copy; OpenStreetMap',
    }).addTo(map);

    L.marker(leConquetEPSG4326, {
      icon: L.divIcon({
        className: 'reference-marker',
        iconSize: [20, 20],
        html: '<div class="circle"></div>',
      }),
    }).addTo(map);

    async function loadDefs(...epsgCodes) {
      const projs = {};
      for (const code of epsgCodes) {
        if (code != 4326) {
          const url = `https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/${code}/esriwkt.txt`;
          const response = await fetch(url);
          const wkt = await response.text();
          proj4.defs(`EPSG:${code}`, wkt);
        }
        projs[code] = proj4(`EPSG:${code}`);
      }
      return projs;
    }

    loadDefs(3946, 4326)
      .then(projs => {
      
        // lng, lat
        const conversionResult = proj4(projs[3946], projs[4326], leConquetEPSG3946);
      
        // lat, lng
        const result = conversionResult.reverse();
        
        console.log(leConquetEPSG4326);
        console.log(result);
      
        L.marker(result).addTo(map);
      
      });

  </script>

</body>

</html>

DEMO

everybody!
Because I had to finish this project very fast, I actually used the new columns I have created, filled with WGS84 data converted from the 3946 ones. All worked fine with WGS84 data.
And Thomas, I thought of that too and I have tested the 3946 data. Nothing was out of order. Only after using the proj4js...
